# Why does React component keep logging console statement when not passed any props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Hi I have these two functional components, can someone please explain why the console statement in the LoxoneApp component is logged every second or so , even though it does not have any props passed to it.

Thanks in advance

```
  import React from "react";
  import LoxoneApp from './LoxoneApp'

  const SetLocation = (props) => {
     return ( 
     <LoxoneApp //rooms = {props.rooms}
                //conts = {props.conts}
                //cats = {props.cats}
                //socket = {props.socket}
                >
     </LoxoneApp>     
      ); 
  }
   export default SetLocation;
```

and

```
   import React from 'react';

   const LoxoneApp = () => {
   console.log('logged from LoxoneApp Component')
      return (
            <p>hell</p>
        );
    } 
    export default LoxoneApp;
```

Comment: Is perfectly find for a component to not use or receive props. Why do you think a component not receiving props should not render?

Comment: Maybe i am completely wrong but I thought a component only rendered on props or state change. If it also renders to keep house in order then where do i place the following const allAudioControls =Helper.getAllAudioControls(props.conts,props.rooms,audioUuid) because at the moment if it is placed where the cosole statement is it  runs every sec

Answer (score 0):

It's rerending because the parent component is doing so, you have to use `React.memo` to prevent renrending of that component.

```
export default React.memo(LoxoneApp);
```

You also can export memo and use it like that:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

...

export default memo(LoxoneApp);
```

An alternative is that you are rendering that component as a child of `SomeArr.map()` and you didn't pass the key attribute to it.